# JPanel not showing up in a JFrame using BorderLayout

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel

I have a JPanel using GridLayout which contains 6 JLabels. If i add only this JPanel to a JFrame everything works fine, but when I add it on BorderLayout.WEST (along with 3 other panels on EAST, CENTER and SOUTH) it just won't show up.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
public class SwingView extends JFrame {
    private DeckLabel[] terrains={
            new DeckLabel(new ImageIcon("assets/graphics/mountains.png"),0),
            new DeckLabel(new ImageIcon("assets/graphics/planes.png"),1),
            new DeckLabel(new ImageIcon("assets/graphics/forest.png"),2),
            new DeckLabel(new ImageIcon("assets/graphics/fields.png"),3),
            new DeckLabel(new ImageIcon("assets/graphics/swamp.png"),4),
            new DeckLabel(new ImageIcon("assets/graphics/desert.png"),5)};
    public SwingView() {
        super("Frame");
        this.setSize(680, 740);
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Utilities.center(this);

        // panels
        //terrains
        JPanel terrainsPanel = new JPanel();
        terrainsPanel.setSize(100, 640);
        terrainsPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 1));
        //map
        JPanel mapPanel = new JPanel();
        mapPanel.setSize(480, 640);
        //info
        JPanel infoPanel = new JPanel();
        infoPanel.setSize(100, 640);
        //chat
        JPanel chatPanel = new JPanel();
        chatPanel.setSize(680, 100);
        chatView.setEditable(false);
        txtChat.addKeyListener(this);
        chatPanel.add(txtChat, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        chatPanel.add(chatView);

    // terrains
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        terrainsPanel.add(terrains[i]);
        }
        this.add(mapPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.add(terrainsPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        this.add(infoPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
        this.add(chatPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    }
}

public class DeckLabel extends JLabel{
    private Image image;
    private int index;
    public DeckLabel(ImageIcon icon,int index){
        this.image=icon.getImage();
        this.index=index;
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(85, 78,
                    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D tg = bi.createGraphics();
        tg.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        // draw basic tile
        tg.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        g.drawImage(bi,0,0,null);
    }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your DeckLabel class sets no text for the JLabel, the component has no minimum and preferred size. So the border layout will assume a size of 0 -> component not visible. The same happens when you use a JPanel.

Call setPreferredSize(), setMinimumSize() or override getMinimumSize()/getPreferredSize().

Comment: This was exactly the issue i was having. I figured it out but I could not answer my own question due to my low reputation. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 3):

plenty issues

- use JPanel instead of JLabel,
- override paintComponent instead of paint for JLabel/JPanel/Swing JComponents
- 1st. code line should be super.pain(Component), or for JPanel to stop repainting (mouse and key events)
- or to use JLabel.setIcon for Image
- something wrong came from Utilities.center(this);, did you tried to layout container
- FlowLayout is default LayoutManager for JPanel, then chatPanel.add(txtChat, BorderLayout.SOUTH); is ignored without missing code line chatPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout)
- txtChat.addKeyListener(this); I'm hope that isn't some of JTextComponents, if yes then to use DocumentListener/Filter instead

Comment: I'm extending JLabel because I had the same problem extending a JPanel. I don't use JLabel.setIcon because i need to paint other things beside the image (like text and shapes). Utilities.center(this) is just used to position the JFrame at the center of the screen.